# How to show link html code with html tags inside it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view-helpers

let's say I have this:

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)

# => <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>
```

But if I need only the href link like `<a href="/profiles/1"><h1>Title</h1><p>some text</p></a>` ?

Are there any rails method for doing this?

EDIT: Soluction for this was block usage like this:

```
<%= link_to(@profile) do %>
<strong><%= @profile.name %></strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
<% end %>
# => <a href="/profiles/1">
   <strong>David</strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
</a>
```

Comment: link_to "", profile_path(@profile) perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit to ask exactly what I'm looking for..

Comment: Just found on docs about using blocks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

```
<%= link_to(@profile) do %>
<strong><%= @profile.name %></strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
<% end %>
# => <a href="/profiles/1">
<strong>David</strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
</a>
```

Hope it helps someone.